# How can I delete current column in an html table using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have an image in table header like this:

```
 <table class="templateTable">
      <thead>
      <tr>
              <th><img src="/Images/delete.png" /></th>
              <th><img src="/Images/delete.png" /></th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
     <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
     <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

I want when I click the image that it deletes the current column from the able. The table doesn't have an id attribute. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use index based remove

```
$('.templateTable thead img').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $td = $this.parent(),
        index = $td.index() + 1;
    $(this).closest('table').find('tr > :nth-child(' + index + ')').remove();
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xc2e53s2/)